# PowerApps Form (SharePoint customized), receiving expected table value error on Lookup formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, power-automate, powerapps-forms

I have a People field in my form with its defaultselectedvalue = LookUp('Travel Request Approval Workflow',Project in DataCardValue5.Text).ProjectManager.  This people field gets changed via Power Automate workflows several times during a request approval process.  But each time the flow changes this field, it reverts back to the original value.  I'd like to set a condition on it's property so that when the Status field is "Not Started", it uses this, but when the Status is anything other than this, set it to Parent.Default...hoping that works.  But I'm trying this, which isn't working:

If(DataCardValue29.Text = "Not Started", LookUp('Travel Request Approval Workflow',Project in DataCardValue5.Text).ProjectManager, Parent.Default)

Gives me an expected table value error.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this multiple selection people field? Is this a combo box or drop down control? Can you add a screenshot of where you are adding this formula and the complete error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LookUp` function finds the first record in a table that satisfies a formula. If the formula doesn’t return a table, you’ll get an "Expected table value" error.

Try this:

```
If(
    DataCardValue29.Text = "Not Started", 
    LookUp('Travel Request Approval Workflow', Project = DataCardValue5.Text, ProjectManager), 
    Parent.Default
)
```